# Laravel 5 Authorize User to see certain Buttons

Tags: php, laravel-5, authorize

I just started learning Laravel 5 and came across a problem i could't solve:
How to tell that a certain user can only see certain things.

For example if i view a profile which is not my own, the "Edit Profile" button should not be visible. But if i look at my own profile this button should be visible.

What i already got is to authorize certain requests. For example to authorize a user to actually update a profile:

```
public function updateProfile(Profile $profile, UpdateProfile $request){
      //update the given profile
}
```

So UpdateProfile is here a Request Class which has a authorize() and a rule() method and in the authorize() Method i check if the logged User is updating his own profile.

So i thought maybe i can use the authorize() method on its own, but i am not really sure how.

Now of course i could always check sth like:

```
if($user -> userID == Auth::user() -> userID)
```

But what if i need to check sth more complex, for example when i write a post and want to show a delete button for that post i want to check:
Is the user admin, if not is the user writer of that post, if any of this is true, show delete button.

So my question would be, where would i check sth like this in laravel 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a `userCanEdit` method on your `Post` class. Something like this:

```
function userCanEdit(User $user)
{
    return $user->isAdmin() || $this->user_id == $user->id;
}
```

And then just call it on your view:

```
@if ($post->userCanEdit(Auth::user()))
    <a href="{{ url("edit/{$post->getId()}") }}">Edit</a>
@endif
```

The advantage of this is that you keep your view clean and centralize the business logic in a single, reusable, method. If the definitions for a user who can edit a post ever change, that is the only place you'll have to worry about.

Comment: with the "Post" class you mean the Post Model class right?

Comment: Yes. (Answer too short)

Answer (score 0):

> So my question would be, where would i check sth like this in laravel 5?

In your views. For example, let's assume that you are loading a blog content like this:

```
// controller

public function showPost(Post $post){
    return view('views.post', ['post' => $post]);
}
```

In the view, we want that only the author make changes to it.

```
// post view

<h2>{{ $post->getTitle() }}</h2>

@if ($post->getAuthor()->getId() === Auth::user()->getId())
    <a href="{{ url("edit/{$post->getId()}") }}">Edit</a>
@endif
```

As you can see above, if the author is the same user as the authenticated, then she/he can see an editing link for this post.

Comment: You have to be sure, that the user is also allowed to send a post request? Or will the missing _token protect this?

Comment: the `_token` just verify if the request was made by you (as a browser user) and not a programming/external resource like a robot or software. The server validation is done as the OP did making a Request class